# How to send a POST request with JSON body?

Tags: python, json, http, post

I am trying to send a `POST` request. For this request, I want to send a `JSON` in the body but this is not working and it gives an error saying: `can't concat str to bytes`. What is the correct way to submit a `POST` request with a `JSON` body?

```
import http.client, urllib.parse

def update_status(status, versionId):
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(server_ip, server_port)
    body = {
        "status": status,
        "id": versionId
    }
    print("body:", body)
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
    conn.request("POST", "", body, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print("response status:", response.status)
    print("response reason:", response.reason)
    return response
return update_status
```

Comment: Please consider using the [requests](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) module :)

Comment: @hansolo or at the very least, [`urlib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yep, the very least. But i'd go with `requests` if possible

Comment: I concur. It's a waste of time to try and to do HTTP communication with low-level modules like `urllib` when a feature-complete and very usable high-level module like `requests` is available.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using requests module. As easy as it looks below:

```
import requests

body = {"key": "value"}
response = requests.post("http://<SOME_URL>", json=body)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize data first.

```
data = json.dumps(body)
data = data.encode('utf8')
conn.request("POST", "", data, headers)
```